# fread chunkwise aligned by Newline

Tags: c, fread

How i can set the fread Pointer for every Chunk?

I need to Move the Pointer to Last newline.

https://onlinegdb.com/cKPh-B-Jt

```
int main()
{
 int intsize = 100;
 char *buffer[intsize];
 buffer[intsize - 1] = '\0';    
 FILE *fp = fopen ("list.txt", "r");
 int cnt=0;
 while (fread (buffer, intsize-1, 1, fp) == 1)
 {
      printf ("loop %d\n", cnt);
      int nlpos = intsize - 1;
      while (buffer[nlpos] != '\n')
      {
          nlpos--;
      }
      fseek(fp,nlpos,SEEK_CUR);
      buffer[nlpos + 1] = '\0';
 }
}
```

Comment: You better call `fread (buffer, 1, intsize-1, fp)` so you get the actual number of bytes read.

Comment: "_For streams opened in text mode, fseek and _fseeki64have limited use, because carriage return–linefeed translations can cause fseek and _fseeki64to produce unexpected results._"

Comment: Also, you are seeking backward from SEEK_CUR, so it should be negative.

Comment: Why not use `fgets` to read lines?

Comment: I try to read chunks of 150MB for increased read Overhead in 1GB File. Try to read from File With Maximum read Speed.

Comment: Thanks, IT was the wrong decrement variable for fseek.. but you explain the real Problem. In First Case Open the File With "rb".